# How to search a html tag name in html file on google drive?

Tags: html, google-drive-api

I uploaded HTML files saved on my computer using Google Drive File Stream to search later.However, even if I enter a html tag name in the search window of Google Drive, the result does not return.

for example， like this index.html on google drive:

```
<div>
  <p>
    first p
  </p>
</div>
```

When I want to search for "div", enter div in the search window, but no results appear.
On the other hand, if enter "first", results appear.

why can't I search "div"

Comment: Are you asking about the Google drive api or the google drive web application?

Comment: I think this question is about the web application and should probably be posted in [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I simply want to find files containing the word ”div” from the Google Drive search window.

Comment: In effect, it seems to ignore html tags. Interestingly, this only happens if the file extension is html. For example, if it's txt, it finds the tags, even when content is exactly the same. Why do you want to look for html tags? Would it be a valid workaround to change the extension of the files you want to upload?